# PHP prepare SELECT

Tags: php, select, prepared-statements

estoy intentando en mi webService hacer un **SELECT** para almacenar el resultado (que siempre será una fila única) en variables de php para un posterior **INSERT**

Este es mi código:

```
    $stmt = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM pl WHERE usuario = :usuario AND id = :id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    
    $stmt -> execute(); 
    $results = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    
    if($stmt -> rowCount() > 0)   { 
        foreach($results as $p) { 
    
            $tipo = $p->tipo;
            $info= $p->info;
            $date = $p->date;

echo("Actualizo");
    

       }
   }
```

He comprobado el valor de las variables `$usuario` y `$id` que se reciven mediante un **$_POST** y son correctas.

También puse un echo para saber si se eejcutaba el **SELECT**, pero no me sale en lo que devuelve el servidor, por lo que `$stmt` no se está ejecutando o no está entrando en el `if`.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes probar a hacer un print_r($results) después del fetchAll, ¿tendrá algo que ver el espació en blanco entre $stmt -> fetchAll()?

Comment: Gracias por la rapidez en contestar @Vicent, l printf_r me pone: Array

Comment: Si haces un print_r($results) pero con $results = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) de esta forma. Por otra parte la consulta del select funciona si la ejecutas en el gestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de que puedes hacer el INSERT basándote en el mismo SELECT con algo como:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES(SELECT ... FROM ...)
```

En tu código se aprecian errores, redundancias y prácticas no recomendadas:

1. [El Manual de PHP es claro con respecto a `rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php), te dice que no deberías confiar en él para consultas del tipo `SELECT`. Si quieres saber si este SELECT trae datos simplemente verifica el estado de `$results`.

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto PDOStatement asociado fue una sentencia SELECT, algunas bases de datos podrían
> devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
> este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
> y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

2. Este bucle tiene un error: `foreach($results as $) {`, no indicas nombre para la variable del `as`. Además, ¿por qué usas un bucle cuando dices que esperas una sola fila? Si esperas una sola fila tampoco deberías usar `fetchAll`. Simplemente usa `fetch` y lee los resultados directamente, sin bucle, dado que esperas **una sola fila**.

El código debería funcionar así:

```
#Variable de control
$outPut=array();
if($bdd) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM pl WHERE usuario = :usuario AND id = :id LIMIT 1";
    if( $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql) ) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);    
        $stmt -> execute(); 
        $results = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);    
        if($results)   {  
            $tipo = $results->tipo;
            $info= $results->info;
            $date = $results->date;
            #Hacer el INSERT o lo que quieras
            $outPut['msg']="Insertaremos los datos";
        } else {
            $outPut['error']="Cero filas encontradas";
        }
    } else {
        #Cambiarlo por error personalizado
        $outPut['error']=sprintf("Error SQL: %s",$bdd->errorInfo()[2]);
    }
} else {
    $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
}
#Test, hacer lo que necesites con $outPut
var_dump($outPut);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! he cambiado lo que me has dicho y me muestra ERROR. Hay alguna manera de que el servidor mande la consulta con los valores para probarla en phpMyAdmin? Es que si que hay un registro con los valores de $id y $usuario

Comment: @wiki, ahí ERROR puede significar dos cosas: o que no hay filas con esos criterios o que hay un error en la consulta o que la conexión no es válida... ahora edito para escribir un código más específico.

Comment: @wiki revisa la nueva versión del código. Es más largo, pero es un código en el cual se preven todos los posibles errores y se van controlando mediante una variable `$outPut`. Ejecutando ese código podrás saber en qué punto exacto está fallando. Yo recomiendo programar siempre de este modo, pues muchas veces se ignora el control de errores, que es una parte fundamental de todo programa bien escrito. No se debería nunca programa de una forma ingenua, pensando que las cosas irán siempre bien.

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS.  Es un gran código para llevar a cabo buenas prácticas de programación. A parte de ahora lo usaré para todas mis consultas. Funciona correctamente!!

Comment: @wiki me alegro de que te haya sido útll. Saludos.